# PHP Formdata have to be triggered with JS/JQ (?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to run a php file/function without entering the page?
I mean it is really disturbing if you create for example a chat app and when you submit your message the whole page get reloaded.

I've tried AJAX but didn't worked. Is it impossible to post the text of the `chat_area` to the PHP file?

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
    <textarea id="chat_area" name="chat_text" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea>
    <input id="chat_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Posten">
</form>

<?php
    session_start();
    include_once( "database.php" );
    if( $_POST["chat_area"] ){
        $name = $_SESSION["firstname"]
        $time = "[" . date( "H:i", time() + 3600 ) . "]";
        $message = $_POST["chat_area"]
        mysql_query( "INSERT INTO chat( name, time, message ) VALUES ('$name', '$time', '$message' )" );
    }
?>
```

Comment: No its not impossible! Try reading the JQuery [manual](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: Is there another way? I'm just creating a chat so there must be a way..

Comment: Use AJAX to send a request to the server without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's default behaviour of the form. For chat-like app, you should use ajax. Not only for posting the form data, but also for receiving messages from backend app. Otherwise, you'll have to reload a page to check whether or not you got some new messages.

With jQuery you could use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop the default action of the form to be triggered, and then post the data to PHP.

You should split your app to 2 files. Main page, and file, where all the data is sent to (and received from).

**Your front end**:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // rest of the PHP, if any...
?>

<form method="POST">
  <textarea id="chat_area" name="chat_text" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea>
  <input id="chat_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Posten">
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#chat_submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          type     : "POST",
          url      : 'your_php_file.php',
          dataType : 'text',
          data     :{
            message : $('#chat_area').val()
          },
          success  : function(data){
            if(data == 'success'){
              // E.g.: append the message to chat area after it is successfully stored in DB.
            }
          },
          complete : function(status){
            // call on complete
          },
          error    : function(response){
            // call when error
          }
        });
     });
  });

</script>
```

**PHP** (your_php_file.php):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once("database.php");
  if( isset($_POST["message"]) ){
    $name = $_SESSION["firstname"];
    $time = "[" . date( "H:i", time() + 3600 ) . "]";
    // a little of safety:
    $unsafe_message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $safe_message = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_message);
    mysql_query
      ( "INSERT INTO chat( name, time, message ) 
      VALUES
      ('$name', '$time', '$safe_message' )" ) or die('error');
      echo 'success';
  }else{
     echo 'error';
  }
?>
```

Comment: So, I've im using ajax, is it possible to call the text in the php file?

Comment: www.m7-studios.de                username: test password: test .. php data is not insert in database.

Comment: There is missing a semicolon after `$name = $_SESSION["firstname"]` and `$message = $_POST["chat_area"]` in your original PHP script . (updated my answer)

Comment: thank you! even little mistakes can be critical. chat works as you can see.